# How to move Thunderbird account settings to a new computer

Tags: thunderbird

On PC A, I have Thunderbird (3.0) running with several mail accounts.
Now I want to move one account (with settings and stored mails) to a new PC B.

I found no functions in Thunderbird to export account settings.

Any hints ?

Comment: You should provide the operating system running on both computer, the paths were the mails and settings are stored differ between operating systems.

Answer (score 2):

You can just copy the whole profile, for a step-by-step guide [look here](http://support.mozillamessaging.com/de/kb/Profiles#_Moving_a_profile). You don't have to edit the profile.ini if the path stays the same on the new computer (e.g. if you're using the same Windows version on both).

Essentially, you just find the profile and copy it to the new computer. The profile contains all mails and settings.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows you can use [MozBackup](http://www.mozbackup.de/). It's a very convenient tool for backup and restore of Firefox and Thunderbird profiles. You can also use ist for migration as migration is just another case of backup/restore.