# Changing Computers - Transfering email in Thunderbird

Tags: windows, thunderbird

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to move Thunderbird account settings to a new computer](https://superuser.com/questions/199758/how-to-move-thunderbird-account-settings-to-a-new-computer)

I am changing computers and would like to take the email I currently have in Thunderbird (this includes local folders etc) and transfer everything to the new computer. How do I do this and keep everything intact? (Both computers are windows os)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way to do this is to use a tool specifically designed for the job - i use [mozbackup](http://mozbackup.jasnapaka.com/), which is a lovely wizard driven backup software which backs up user data including local folders and accounts.

If you want to do it manually for some reason, mozilla knowledge base has a [list of what files to move](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Transferring_data_to_a_new_profile_-_Thunderbird) to copy data over to a new profile - your profile files should be in %appdata%/thunderbird/Profiles/.

Comment: The automatic way works for me, thanks for the link and information.